# Passing on a return value from one function to another in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function

I am new to TS so please be patient. I am trying to pass on the return value from one function into another. As a parameter and also call it from outside the function.

I have tried declaring the variable as public but that is no use as all the function inside the class unless defined otherwise are treated as public. Hence I am not sure where to go with this.

```
class generateXML{
    controlPrefix: string;
    constructor(name: string){
        this.controlPrefix = name;
        console.log('<Group>' + name + 'Control' + '</Group>')
    }

    controlCategoryName(uniqueName : string){
        let controlDisplayName: string = this.controlPrefix + ' ' + uniqueName;
        let controlName: string = controlDisplayName.replace(/\s/g, "");

        console.log(`<DisplayName>${controlDisplayName}</DisplayName>`);
        console.log(`<Name>${controlName}</Name>`);
        return uniqueName;
    }

    controlXMLPropertyGenerator(propertyName: string){
        let propertyXML: string = propertyName.toLowerCase();
        let propertyFriendlyName: string = propertyName;
        console.log(`<Prop ID="${propertyName}" friendlyname="${propertyFriendlyName}" category="${uniqueName}"`);
    }

    controlXMLPropertyGeneratorFriendlyName(uniqueName){

    }
}


let genXML = new generateXML('Control Name');
genXML.controlCategoryName('Control Category Name');
genXML.controlXMLPropertyGenerator('Control Property Name');
```

In the function **controlXMLPropertyGenerator**, I would like to log the value of "*uniqueName*" which is a parameter from the **controlCategoryName** function. 
Also, I would like to pass "*uniqueName*" as parameter for **controlXMLPropertyGeneratorFriendlyName** function.